# I want to display the image sent by react axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to send an image with react axios and return a character string, but I have a question here.
The backend is an API that puts an image and returns a character string.

## I want to ask a question.

1. How can I display the image to be sent on the screen?
2. How can I display the string returned after sending the image?

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
 
class FileUpload extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedFile:'',
        }
 
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }
 
    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
          })
    }
 
    submit(){
        const data = new FormData() 
        
        data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
        console.warn(this.state.selectedFile);
        let url = "http://localhost:8000/upload.php";
 
        axios.post(url, data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data 
        })
        .then(res => { // then print response status
            console.log(res.data)
        })
 
    }
 
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <br /><br />
 
                            <h3 className="text-white">React File Upload Example - Tutsmake.com</h3>
                            <br />
                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label className="text-white">Select File :</label>
                                    <input type="file" className="form-control" name="upload_file" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
 
                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>名前確認</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )  
    }
}
 
export default FileUpload;
```

Comment: `returns a character string` what does this mean ? return the image url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood

this is how to get a preview of selected image

```
const [file] = e.target.files;
setImgPrev(URL.createObjectURL(file));
// imgPrev state will be the src of your preview image
```

and to get the string that returned after sending the html request you have to listen to the response that will come from axios

```
axios.post(url, data)
  .then(res => setRes(res))
  .catch(err => return err)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made image uploader and preview the uploaded image before sent to the BE with API. I also use normal html input with type file. May be my code can be used in yours.

```
const handleImageChange = (value) => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  const image = value.target.files[0];
  setSavedFile(image);

  reader.onload = () => {
    setMainImage({
      img: reader.result,
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}

...
...
<input
  onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e)
/>
```

the image that will rendered saved with `setMainImage()`, the image source is in `reader.result`. For the `setSavedFile` is used to save the file uploaded.

For the question number 2, you can normally save the response from the API to state and show the state in the html element